# Alpha masks with a solidify modifier - objects with no edge?

Tags: node-editor, transparency

I am trying to use planes with a solidify modifier and a transparency mask to quickly test the look of different images for a lightbox I'm making. However Im having trouble getting the rim of the object to appear where the transparency is used. [image]

Its a simple node setup:

[image]

Does anyone know how to bridge that gap? the fill rim checkbox on the solidify modifier only does the outside edges, not the edges which are formed by the mask (factor in the mix shader node).

To clairfy, it needs to be nice and simple so tha the image can be changed and the model quickly updated without having to model meshes or adjust booleans. but i need that gap closed or it obviously looks funny.

Cheers,

Dan